# trying online programming first time factorial giving wrong answer

Tags: c++

This is a factorial program,I made on a coding site.Kindly help me find why its wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, f = 1;
    int t, a[100];
    cin >> t;//enter test cases
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
        cin >> a[i];//enter all the cases one by one
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= a[i]; j++)
            f = f*j;
        cout << f;//displays each factorial
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to initialise f to 1 for each test case.

Comment: thats because since you have declared the `factorial variable` outside the scope it is preserving the previous value hence giving wrong results from second test case.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just a tip for your future questions: if your program is giving erroneous output, please specify the test input, the desired output and the real output. Saying it gives "wrong results" does not give us enough information to help you. Additionally, you might want to check [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._"

Answer (score 3):

You should reinitialize the value of `f` back to 1 at the start of each test case.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, f = 1;
    int t, a[100];
    cin >> t;//enter test cases
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
        cin >> a[i];//enter all the cases one by one
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        f = 1 // add this line
        for (j = 1; j <= a[i]; j++)
            f = f*j;
        cout << f;//displays each factorial
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://codebuddy.co.in/problems/FACT. sir,kindly give me the solution of this factorial ques. even after correcting that silly mistake,Im not able to correct it may be due to some modulo thing.kindly correct it so i can learn

Comment: @rohankhanna3318: your whole approach is wrong - note that there can be  up to 1000 test cases (not 100), and N can be as big as 1000. 1000! is a huge number (it has 2568 decimal digits), which can not be represented as an int. The answer only needs to be calculated modulo 1000000007 however - you will need to apply a little [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory)...

Answer (score 0):

You should reinitialize the value for your `factorial variable f` each time you are computing the factorial, also you need not use array to store all the asked factorial cases unnecessarily waste of memory.

Here is the optimized solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, f,num;
    int t;
    cin >> t; //enter test cases
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        f = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
            f = f * j;
        }
        //displays each factorial
        cout << f << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```